# Animated GIF as avatar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-picture

Why are animated GIF images not displayed properly (not moving) if used as one's avatar?

Is there a reason for imposing such restriction on user icons?

Comment: Because they are annoying?

Comment: That's like your opinion, man :) Was there a request by users for this feature?

Comment: There's [bug reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/animated-gifs-are-animating) from users when the anti-animation thing fails. Because they're hugely annoying.

Comment: @Alxg: It's common bloody sense mate

Answer (score 52):

Because if they *were* allowed, this would be my avatar on all sites:

(possible seizure risk - rapid black/white flashing)

> [image]

Comment: Inb4 someone spams that in all the chatrooms.

Comment: *Dude that is so annoy...* `Shog9 supreme leader. Shog9 world domination I will serve for you. Shog9. Shog9 have me commanded. Shog9 highest mod of all. Shog9.`

Comment: Yeah, the casing in this one is really jarring! (Note: My FF settings don't loop GIFs.)

Comment: This kind of argument would apply to any feature: "If we allow comments, there will be comments like <something bad>" etc.

Answer (score -5):

Would totally want smaller sized version of this as avatar ... totally ...

[image: meow]
<sub>(source: [catgifpage.com](https://www.catgifpage.com/gifs/246.gif))</sub>