# Are animated GIFs allowed as avatars?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, users, profile-picture

I just saw an animated GIF as an user's avatar. I'll avoid linking the user profile here for obvious reasons, but here is a GIF showing their GIF:

[image]

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271938/5768908) GIFs were not allowed as avatar images, but obviously something changed since then, because it's working now (I searched both SO Meta and SE Meta but I couldn't find any post regarding this).

Are they allowed? In my opinion they are quite distracting and annoying, and should not be permitted.

Comment: Was it actually animating in their profile or on posts they made?

Comment: @Makoto It's animating everywhere: questions list, post and profile. I just edited the question with a GIF taken from the questions list.

Comment: I'm able to locate this user's profile based on your screenshot, and have reset it for now. Thanks.

Comment: I just saw this link in the Q/A I mentioned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239035/380572

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not aware of any policy changes allowing animated avatars in user profiles, so I have reset this user's profile image.

In this case, it seems that the image was loaded externally as the user signed up using their Google account which had an animated gif as their profile image.

[There was validation for Google profile images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/animated-gifs-are-animating) but it appears to be broken now, so I'm tagging this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). In the meantime if you come across any user with an animated image, please flag any of the user's posts and let the moderators know. The good news is that it seems users are no longer able to re-opt into using a Google-hosted profile image after the initial sign-up.

---

found these related posts on MSE:

- [Can I have an animated profile picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272911/can-i-have-an-animated-profile-picture)
- [Is it possible for us to use an animated GIF as our profile picture or in our personal information?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288711/is-it-possible-for-us-to-use-an-animated-gif-as-our-profile-picture-or-in-our-pe)
- gifs from Google was supposed to be converted previously?
  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/animated-gifs-are-animating

Comment: jeez you should put an epilepsy warning on that link D:

Answer (score 14):

Looks like at some point the "stop animating this plz" code we had for Google avatars stopped working. It's entirely possible that it was never supposed to be working in the first place. But either way, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417423/google-hpis-dont-animate-gifs/35417778#35417778), we now have new code in place that appears to work. For how long? There's one way to find out. :)

Comment: When did that code get released? I'm still seeing animated GIF profile pictures, like [this users profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10943551/nik3141).

Comment: @TimothyG. That particular avatar doesn't animate for me... but only because it has a different URL format, so the fix I built out on Friday actually breaks those images altogether. ‍♂️ Thanks for the heads up, I'll fix this up.

Comment: Looks like it lasted for about three years, there are now users who can freely upload animated avatars, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421458).