# Animated avatar - is there a moderator willing to reset and stop that user from keep doing this?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, declined-flags, avatar, animation

I recently raised a flag over one of [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13253010/thedemons) posts, this is the flag:

> User exploiting imgur bug to have animated avatar.

The flag was declined with this kind message:

> If SE doesn't want animated avatars, it's their job to fix it. Post a bug report instead

But hey, I [did post a bug report already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322457/animated-avatars-in-user-profile-and-newsletter), three years ago. A staff member replied and it's clearly implied that animated avatars **are not allowed in Stack Exchange**.

The bug is not on the SE side; it's on the Imgur side, and sadly they lied saying they fixed it, but there's nothing we can do except teach the users that animated avatars are not allowed. They are annoying.

I'm not going to flag again because I prefer to not get flag banned, but I am asking the moderators of this site to reconsider, and hopefully reset the animated profile.

Another proof that animated avatars are now allowed in Stack Exchange is [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164023/animated-gif-profile-pic-on-stackoverflow-doesnt-animate?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment477584_164023) by a developer:

> Okay, let me spell this out. Disabling animation in profile pictures even if you uploaded an animated gif is by design. If Imgur fixes their resizing so that it lets animations through, we'll have to find another way to disable them. See Tim Stone's answer on this question as well.

Comment: That bug report you submitted also has the following stated: *"content uploaded during that window is the way it is, so removing the gifs now would require the user re-upload the image."* So the person who needs to "resolve" the issue is the user in question, no one else. Personally, I don't see the problem...

Comment: @Larnu they uploaded the avatar way after that bug report, very recently. The user was not even part of Stack Overflow when I posted that bug report, they are exploiting an **existing imgur bug**, on purpose. They will not upload a non-animated avatar unless forced to do that.

Comment: If there's a *new* bug, then report a new bug. Though if the bug is on Imgr, you need to report the bug there, not on [meta.se]. Posting about it here isn't going top "fix" anything, as the user could just reuse the bug on the external site.

Comment: @Larnu when someone do something against the rules, moderators exist to stop them, by suspension. This is not different.

Comment: Where in the rules does it state that animated profile images are not allowed? (Stack Overflow making efforts to make an animated gif a static gif doesn't make a rule.)

Comment: @Larnu see my edit, with the developer's comment. And yes, if something is by design, it means SE does not want it to be otherwise.

Comment: That isn't a rule; I'm asking where in the rules it states it isn't allowed. The only place [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) discusses animations is in terms of licencing. The problem isn't Stack Overflow, or the user, here, it's the bug on Imgr and (presumably) your dislike of the (animated) image.

Comment: This is not a bug but rather a feature of Imgur, and it **could** potentially be prevented from SE side. Considering that this *bug* is not dangerous, it could only be abused [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271940/13253010), and SE has no bug report award, I decided that I'd rather not report it and keep it to myself. I understand that it could be annoying to see animated gifs while you're trying to read something, but unless SE fixes it, I'll keep my avatar - as it is not against the rule. I've also changed it to a less annoying gif since you commented on my mentioned post.

Comment: Honestly, unless the gif is actively disruptive or damaging, I don't see why mods should put time and effort into something that. At the end of the day when this is something that honestly requires SE to prevent it for it to be in any way work efficient. SE [has options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276742/6296561) that do not depend on imgur fixing their stuff, so blaming imgur doesn't really get them out of this one

Comment: And as already mentioned, if their fix has regressed, that's cause for a _new_ bug report. Regressions happen constantly thanks to SE's unwillingness to set up regression testing

Comment: I am curious now,  what if that user shares how to do this to people and others start doing it too... would that be a problem? Would it be a problem if say *I* start using it too :p?

Comment: And that right there is why a crackdown is a waste of time akin to mass-hunting the far too many spam profiles. We do not have an easy way to control it or detect it. Ergo, with the exception of disruptive or damaging gifs, it's a waste of mod time, and SE needs to fix it if they still care.

Comment: @Larnu I did change my avatar to make it less annoying, as mentioned in my comment above, here is [the old avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Jch.gif) for reference.

Comment: Didn't notice your comment, apologies, @thedemons . Though I suspect that the reason that the OP thinks it "annoying" here is because it's animated, and nothing more; that you've change it is unlikely going to "annoy" them less when it's still animated, but I am assuming their opinion on the matter.

Comment: @Larnu this, and actually just having someone exploit a bug is annoying on its own accord.

Comment: Regardless of whether staff/developers don't want animated avatars, there's an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389318/) by a site mod that very explicitly says "*...  if you come across any user with an animated image, please flag any of the user's posts and let the moderators know.*" which seems to contradict how this particular flag was handled. I don't have a strong opinion on the matter either way (though my preference is to allow animated avatars, as I can't see how they cause any harm), but the mod guidance should be clarified so that it's consistent.

Comment: @cigien huh, thanks for finding it. Well, each mod is different, it's really a pity there's no direct rule against using animated avatars, it's just implied due to SE not allowing it. And the harm is distracting the readers, who expect to just read answers, not be overwhelmed with moving objects all around the place.

Comment: *"just having someone exploit a bug is annoying on its own"* which is why you need to raise a [[meta-tag:bug]] on [meta.se], @ShadowTheKidWizard ; you're yet to do so. Then, if Stack Overflow want to, they can address the issue and stop future users using the exploit. Plug the hole first.

Comment: @Larnu not relevant. Suppose you walk outside in the street, and see an open door of a private house. You can enter the house of a stranger and explore it. Will you do it, just because you can and that other person didn't close the door? That's my point.

Comment: If it's not relevant, and you don't want the bug fixed, then don't complain about it, @ShadowTheKidWizard ... To use the analogy you've used: *I*, personally, don't care that the person has left their door open, so I don't do anything. You, on the other hand, *do* care so why are you not closing the door or letting the resident know?

Comment: @Larnu I can't close the door myself, and letting the resident know can take a long while. Until then, I prefer people to use common sense and not barge into the open door.

Comment: Then leave it be, and the problem goes away. If it's bothering your that much, raise a [[meta-tag:bug]], if it's not, then do nothing. Either way, I've voted to close this, as it seems that you don't want to discuss anything here.

Comment: The fact that there's [actual code on SE's end](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389865/1835379) dedicated to un-animating the avatar means that those are not allowed... Bug or not, this flag was incorrectly handled. The fact that the bug exists doesn't mean anyone can just abuse it... I'd assume resetting a user's profile image is a relatively trivial action in the mod tools? :D

Comment: @Cerbrus if only mods would think the same way, but they don't, and sadly we can't force them.

Comment: We can start a petition! That'll show them!

Comment: @Cerbrus to be honest I was very surprised and disappointed to see that these days people are fine with animated avatars, rules aside. So my next step is going to be MSE feature request asking to mention in the ToS that animated avatars are not allowed, then I can re-fuel this discussion and nullify all the objections.

Comment: Well, the problem is: I personally don't really have a problem with the example you provided, but we can't differentiate between smooth subtle animation, and FLASHY in your face stuff...

Comment: just use obnoxious animated avatars till it's fixed.

Comment: The existing Stack Exchange policy and consensus are clear that animated avatars are not permitted. If a user desires to have an animated avatar, then they need to get that policy and consensus changed prior to using such an animated avatar, regardless of if it's technologically possible to upload and display an animated avatar. Yes, it would be *much* better if Stack Exchange enforced the policy technologically, but that's clearly not fully in place at this time.

Comment: @Makyen why was this marked as duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389316/? That question's answers can be summarized as "no they're not, I've reset this user's avatar" and "this should be prevented to happen again from now on". Edit: you appear to have reset this user's avatar, which is nice.

Comment: @CodeCaster Because the answers to this question would be identical to the answers on the duplicate. The SE policy and community consensus haven't changed. If a user wants to use an animated avatar, then the policy and community consensus need to change *first*.

Comment: @Makyen there's still a major problem, of flags being declined. Most people would just move on, as many here advised me already, instead of insisting and pursuing it further.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Your flag could have been *much* better, which would likely have prevented it from being declined. As you've indicated, all you said was "User exploiting imgur bug to have animated avatar.", which gave the responding moderator no real context, nor made it clear what you expected to happen. Yes, it would have been good for the moderator to go do research, but they *shouldn't have to* when you were already aware of what the policy is. You could have, and should have, been more explicit in your flag as to what you expected to happen and why.

Comment: @Makyen I made a flag before shadow, provided the MSE links, and made a clear actionable request, _and_ got my flag declined. My flag said: "_this user somehow has an animated avatar, which is not supposed to be allowed/possible (meta.stackexchange.com/q/322457/997587, and meta.stackexchange.com/q/272911/997587). I noticed this yesterday, and today I noticed that it changed to a different animated avatar (Ie. not a bug due to the 2018-2019 server outage). Not sure how this happened, but can you please reset their avatar?_". Got declined as "_declined - Not our problem. Post a bug report_".

Comment: " If Imgur fixes their resizing so that it lets animations through, we'll have to find another way to disable them." Can't Stack Exchange just... inspect the data to see if it represents an animation? Or even add some client-side code to guard against that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel both are technically absolutely possible

Comment: I have posted a bug report: [Imgur feature allows animated avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383785/1272872)